# How can I copy on select in the OS X Terminal like PuTTY does?

Tags: macos, terminal, copy-paste

That PuTTY option to select and then right-click to paste is the best invention after the mouse. Is there any way to make Terminal in OS X do this? Hack the source code? Install something?

Is the source code for the OS X Terminal publicly available?

Comment: I suggest changing the accepted answer to the one with 4x the upvotes that doesn't require an install.

Comment: '..best invention after mouse', plus one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install SIMBL and then install [TerminalCopyOnSelect](http://blog.s21g.com/articles/1077).

[image]

> - At first, you should install [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php).
> - Download [the zipped plugin file](http://blog.s21g.com/blobs/0bd3389bb8e8239bba5255607e22f782/TerminalCopyOnSelect.bundle.zip) I mentioned above and expand it.
> - Copy the extracted file "TerminalCopyOnSelect.bundle" to the plugin directory which is located at ~/Library/Application
>     Support/SIMBL/Plugins/
> - Terminate all processes of Terminal.app and restart it.

Comment: This is cool. Already something, but what I really wanted was a:

CopyOnSelectAndPaste

Like putty!

Comment: As @Arjan said, Terminal can do this: Choose **Edit > Paste Selection** (or Shift-Comamnd-V) or Middle-Click, the latter of which I assume is what you meant by “right-click” in your original question.

Comment: Despite any plugin quality, installing terminal Third Party Plugins is a bad idea.

Comment: @ChrisPage people want to copy from terminal by selecting, and then paste elsewhere. 'Paste selection' doesn't do that.

Answer (score 54):

In Terminal, select something and then within the same Terminal window do one of the following:

- click and drag the selection (a bit; the mouse pointer will change), and release to paste (hit Esc while dragging to cancel)

  [image]
- or: paste using [Shift-Command-V](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/terminal/trmlshtcts/mac)
- or: paste using the middle mouse button

Comment: I use Cmd-Shift-V all the time!

Comment: Thanks for the middle mouse button tip! Feels like redemption!

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer ;-)

Comment: I was looking for this because wanted to enable "copy on select" however drag and drop option made me happy :p

Comment: Or command right click with default mouse.

Answer (score 10):

[iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/), an alternative to Terminal, can do this.

Comment: And so can Terminal. **Edit > Paste Selection** or Middle-Click if you have a three (or more) button mouse. Or drag the text a few pixels and release.

Answer (score 7):

[iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) also has an option to copy text to the normal clipboard on selection:

[image]

You can remap the middle button to paste from the clipboard:

[image]

Like in Terminal, you can also use shift-command-V (Edit > Paste Special > Paste Selection) to paste the text that is selected elsewhere in the current window.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your 4 questions:

> That putty option to select and then right-click to paste in the best invention after the mouse. Is there anyway to make the terminal do this?

No, you can however select the text you want and drag-n-drop your selection to the command prompt.

> Hack the source code?

Probably can be done through reverse engineering, but why bother for something so trivial, and the fact that it's illegal :P

> Install something?

[iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) as kbisset suggests.

> Are the source code for the mac terminal public available?

No but iTerm's is

Comment: “No, you can however select the text you want and drag-n-drop…” The answer is “Yes”. You can Middle-Click to do the same thing as **Edit > Paste Selection**. “right-click to paste” is likely a typo; either Sergio meant “middle-click to paste” or he’s using a terminal application with a “Paste Selection” contextual menu command.

Comment: Reverse engineering is not illegal in the United States.  Not sure what country you're posting from, though.

Comment: Right click to paste is how it works in Putty (in windows) and I think maybe some Linux based terminal apps also.  I haven't looked into it myself, but Karabiner should be able to "remap" right mouse button to middle mouse button (eg simulate a middle mouse button click) when the Terminal app has focus.

Answer (score 3):

You can launch an X11 server and use xterm. Everything is already in the box.

You can even type `xterm&` in Terminal.app, and X11 will automatically be launched.

Answer (score 2):

my workflow

for copy: cmd-shift-click - it copies full unix paths like putty

for paste: triple click trackpad which works like  middle button of mouse on xwindow or right button in putty (requires: http://clement.beffa.org/labs/projects/middleclick/ )

Answer (score 1):

You could also install [TotalTerminal](http://totalterminal.binaryage.com/) and enjoy hotkey access to a dropdown Quake-style terminal that has a copy-on-select setting too :-)

TotalTerminal augments the existing Terminal and doesn't replace it so I find it a nicer solution than installing and using another app :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you tried the accepted answer; the SIMBL TerminalCopyOnSelect approach but failed with a dialog showing:

```
Terminal 2.5 (v334) has not been tested with the plugin TerminalCopyOnSelect (null)(v0.1.0).
As a precaution, it has not been loaded. Please contact the plugin developer for further information.
```

It's because TerminalCopyOnSelect you downloaded applies only if Terminal.app bundle version is 237 - 240.

You can download and build it yourself from [github](https://github.com/genki/terminalcopyonselect) .

```
git clone https://github.com/genki/terminalcopyonselect.git
cd terminalcopyonselect
open TerminalCopyOnSelect.xcodeproj
# edit Info.plist and set SIMBLTargetApplications's MaxBundleVersion to 400, which is enough for MacOSX Yosemite's Terminal.app
# hit build, and it will copy TerminalCopyOnSelect.bundle under it's proper place: ~/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just select what ever you want with the mouse, then cmd+ right click the mouse, it will copy the selected text and paste it.

Comment: Nice. Command plus two-finger tap on the trackpad works too.

Answer (score 0):

**iTerm2** has been doing this for ages. The thing is the default configuration assigns it to the middle button. If you have a 2-buttons mouse, you need to assign the *paste* action to a single click on the right button through **iTerm -> Preferences -> Pointer -> Bindings -> Paste from Clipboard**. In 2021, this is what the configuration looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, the only way to make the standard Mac OS Terminal behave like putty, is:

- to Select&Copy: hold Command + Shift and double click the text/path you want to copy. It's automatically copied in an "alternative clipboard"
- to paste(putty like): hold Command + Shift and Right-click. The text is automatically pasted for the "alternative clipboard".

Basically, on select&copy&paste it works just like Putty as long as you hold Command + Shift while doing it.

A word about the "alternative clipboard": it seems that if you copy a text using the described workaround, it can only be pasted using the same workaround, otherwise, by doing right-click->paste, it will paste from the standard clipboard