# Copy-on-select, paste-on-middle-click on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, copy-paste

Is there a way to give OS X the usual X-windows behavior where selecting text in any application automatically copies it to the clipboard, and the middle mouse button automatically pastes it?

<kbd>[image: command]</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>[image: command]</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is a little annoying.

Comment: Well, it works as expected in X...don't know of a solution in quartz.

Comment: Bumping the question, because I don't want to ask it again.

Comment: bump too for me... would be great to have this

Comment: I just wanted to ask the same question. I recently started to work on MacOS X at my workplace and I am long time Linux user, this is one hell of a Linux feature I am missing on MacOS.

Comment: You mean you want to give up your ability to replace the selected text with what's on the clipboard?

Comment: As an aside: I don't think it is copied to the clipboard, but simply does not use the clipboard at all?

Comment: The answer is in this thread.

http://superuser.com/questions/62609/mac-terminal-copy-on-select-like-putty

Answer (score 22):

This has already been discussed (and answered) on [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21595/can-i-copy-by-highlighting-and-paste-by-middle-click-on-mac-os-x). The accepted [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/30860/2643) in that discussion was to use Better Touch Tool.

However, all those solutions that suggest using some tool to map a mouse click to Cmd-V do not completely mimic the behaviour of X, where you can have different content in the mouse-controlled buffer and the keyboard-controlled buffer (i.e., you can paste two different strings depending on whether you middle-click or press CTRL-V).

Comment: And more problematic. It doesn't have the "highlight text to copy" feature.

Answer (score 17):

Just for the archives: what you want does actually work in Terminal<sup>†</sup>, but only in the very same Terminal window:

Select some text (and release the mouse button), and use the middle mouse button to paste.

Alternatively, when using the trackpad or a two-button mouse: after selecting, click and drag the selection just a bit; you'll see the pointer change. Now, when you let go of the button, the selected text is pasted at your cursor. Hitting Esc while dragging cancels.

[image: drag and drop]

<sup><sup>†</sup> Of course, Terminal is just one out of many programs. But for me, it is the only place I actually want this behaviour, if only because of [Spiff's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/87470/copy-on-select-paste-on-middle-click-on-mac-os-x#comment-191366) about being able to replace (mouse) selected text with what's on the clipboard.</sup>

Comment: Actually copy/drag text works great for me in any editor target (ie, Terminal, BBEdit, text input box on this page, etc)... you can combine a drag with Exposé and CMD-tab.  Also, if you want to "copy to clipboard", you can just drag to desktop and it will create a text clipping that you can then drag to other locations repeatedly (it's like a visual clipboard in a way).

Answer (score 9):

If you just need it for Terminal then you can install [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com) which is a terminal which has the X windows cut and paste.

Comment: How do I copy-on-select across Terminal <-> Browser <-> Email?

Comment: As I said just for terminal to/from something nothing else

Comment: Unfortunately iTerm feels much slower in responsiveness.

Comment: For the record, iTerm2 (iTerm's successor) can be found here: http://www.iterm2.com/

Answer (score 4):

I just tried Terminal (OS X El Capitan, Version 10.11.5). The process I used is this:

1. Highlight text
2. Holding 1 finger, drag a bit up (the highlighted text moves and green '+' appears)
3. Release and the highlighted text appears in the command line

Comment: Perfect! Works on my Sierra (10.12.6).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a mac so I can't check this out and the content was too long for just a comment so I'm posting it as an answer. Maybe it will prove helpful to others.

**Solution1:**

Go to X11 preferences - highlight "emulate 3 button mouse".

Now middle click = option+click.

Highlight/paste will work just like in Linux.

**Solution2:**

Another way is to install the better touch tool, this allows you to assign your own commands to different mouse/touchpad gestures.

- 1 finger right tap = cmd c (copy) and
- 2 finger tap = cmd v (paste)

It is one step more than the highlight = copy, but still preferable over the keyboard shortcuts.

From the [macworld hintforums](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=78521).

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly the same, but if you select text and right click on it, you do have the option to copy. Once something is on the pasteboard, a right click can paste as well.

I fooled around with my Logitech multi-button mega mouse and couldn't make anything exactly like what you describe, even though one of the options is a "middle click" button.

Theo

Answer (score 1):

As a long time linux user I've been desperatly searching for such functionality in osx. Mark is right - iTerm is the answer plus some settings in the X11 Preferences. [Visit here](http://tjp3000.blogspot.com/2010/12/enable-copy-on-select-in-mac-osx.html) for more info.

Comment: Brilliant !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I am using BetterTouchTool and have configured it to emulate a middle mouse button in Terminal application on three finger click.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER**: I have not tested this because I don't have a mac. But, the content was too large to post as a comment. So, I am posting it as an answer instead.

I am windows user and have implemented exact same function in windows using a script written for a program called Autohotkey.

Now, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332254/autohotkey-alternative-for-mac-os-x) question, IronAHK runs AHK scripts on Mac.

Here's the one I am using for windows (Ofcourse, you would have to tweak it a lot to make it work):

```
    cos_mousedrag_treshold := 20 ; pixels


#IfWinNotActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass

~lButton::
  MouseGetPos, cos_mousedrag_x, cos_mousedrag_y
  keywait lbutton
  mousegetpos, cos_mousedrag_x2, cos_mousedrag_y2
  if (abs(cos_mousedrag_x2 - cos_mousedrag_x) > cos_mousedrag_treshold
    or abs(cos_mousedrag_y2 - cos_mousedrag_y) > cos_mousedrag_treshold)
  {
    wingetclass cos_class, A
    if (cos_class == "Emacs")
      sendinput !w
    else
      sendinput ^c
  }
  return

~mbutton::
  WinGetClass cos_class, A
  if (cos_class == "Emacs")
    SendInput ^y
  else
    SendInput ^v
  return

#IfWinNotActive


;; clipx
^mbutton::
  sendinput ^+{insert}
  return
```

Script credit goes to [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=47816) post.
Try experimenting and comment if you get it to work. 
I'll try to help as much as possible.

Meanwhile, have a look at [this](http://sikuli.org/) as well. But, I don't think it is advanced enough for the function you desire.

Comment: This is an autohotkey script for macOS no?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a native way either. After trying different things I ended up using [TotalTerminal](http://totalterminal.binaryage.com/).

It adds some additional functionality to the terminal app. Besides copy-on-select you can set a global key to bring up the terminal whenever you like.

Answer (score 0):

You might try fiddling with your mouse settings to see if the driver lets you assign the paste function to middle-click. If it doesn't, try looking into [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/).

As for copy-on-select, I am unaware of any software that gives you this functionality, and judging from what I can find on Google, none probably exists.