# Copy on select in OSX (outside of terminal)

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy-on-select, paste-on-middle-click on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/87470/copy-on-select-paste-on-middle-click-on-mac-os-x)

I'd like to know if there's a way to copy-on-select in OSX, even outside of the terminal?

Comment: Consider placing a bounty if you think the question isn't sufficiently answered.

Comment: @slhck: I certainly saw that question, noticed that all of the answers was related to the terminal.. I guess I read that into the question as well. I'll leave this open since it's "on top" but I might just very well offer a bounty later on. Thanks.

Comment: You should have included in your question that you read the other one.  I'm just afraid that what you seek for is not possible, otherwise we would've gotten an answer by now.

Comment: 1:st sentence: sure, I hope ppl read comments. 2:nd: I doubt that someone goes back to a 3 year old question and answers without any incentive.

Comment: The question has 15 upvotes and has been viewed over 5000 times. People who know the solution mostly don't care about the age of a question when they find it on Google.

Comment: @slhck This would be easy on Windows with a tool such as AutoHotkey. Is there no similar software on Mac OSX?

Comment: @iglvzx None that I know of — there's only a few apps that offer this functionality, but nothing system-wide.

Comment: I'd be interested in an answer to this question too. So I put a small bounty on the dupe.