# PuTTY or xterm for Mac?

Tags: mac, macbook, putty, xterm

I am using a MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.5. I am new to this development environment, and previously worked on Windows.

Are there similar tools on Mac like [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) or [xterm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) used on Linux/Windows (SSH client with more handy features than the command-line)?

Comment: XTerm? An SSH client? That's a new one...

Comment: Any recommendations for a good to use ssh client on Mac? I want to have a free one. :-)

Comment: Your mac should include ssh by default, start a terminal and type `ssh` on the command line.

Comment: Thanks Nifle, you normally use built-in terminal for ssh client (and you think the built-in terminal is good enough?), and no need to have any other ssh client for Mac?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) on the Mac, as well as the standard Terminal app.

Comment: Why iTerm is better than standard terminal app?

Comment: I like iTerm because it respects the Home/End/PageUp/PageDown keys that function correctly in windows/linux. In Terminal, mac has a different meaning for what those keys do, and it annoys me.

Comment: Thanks, is iTerm totally free? I did not find charging information on its web site.

Comment: @George2 - Yes, it is on sourceforge, and is totally free.

Comment: FYI, you can change the preferences in Terminal to emulate Windows/Linux Home/End keys etc. http://theandystratton.com/2009/fixing-home-end-page-up-and-page-down-in-leopards-terminal

Comment: That only partially works. It doesn't work inside vim inside screen. Trust me, I have tried for awhile and have been frustrated to no end.

Comment: The first comment on that page lists a vim-compatable solution.

Comment: @ghoppe - `Vim` inside `Screen` is not `Vim` by itself.

Comment: So, you guys think using built-in terminal is good enough and no need to use any other ssh client?

Comment: For basic terminal usage, yes the Built-in client is perfect. If you need any advanced things, i would suggest iTerm

Comment: "advanced things" -- for example? :-)

Comment: Well, for me it was using `screen` in combination with `vim`. On Terminal it went all crazy, in iTerm it works fine.

Answer (score 11):

[Terminal](http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/apps-and-utilities.html#terminal) is built into the operating system. It's free and fulfills much the same purpose as xterm on Linux.

Comment: You think terminal is better than iTerm? Why?

Comment: I don't think it's better. It's just always there. iTerm is a fine Application too.

Answer (score 7):

[iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/) is insanely superior to Terminal and iTerm.

Answer (score 4):

As of 10.5, Mac OS X ships with X11, as well as a few standard X applications (namely xterm, xman and xlogo).

You open an XTerm window by starting X (it's in /Applications/Utilities), and while it's active go to Applications/Terminal, or press cmd+n.

I have no experience with iTerm, but there are a few minor features not present in Apple's terminal, such as mouse support, which do happen to work in XTerm there.

Mac OS X also ships with OpenSSH, which can be started with `ssh` at the command line (from Terminal, iTerm, XTerm, whatever), which is pretty much the best SSH client.

Comment: I don't know iTerm, but Terminal [does have basic mouse support for copy-paste](http://superuser.com/questions/62609/mac-terminal-copy-on-select-like-putty/62659#62659).

Comment: By mouse support, I mean applications having access to the mouse; using the scroll wheel in `less`, full mouse support in vim with `:set mouse=a`, &c. In terminal, you can also use the standard mac keyboard shortcuts to copy and paste (cmd-c, cmb-v).

Comment: X11 is no longer included in the latest OSX v10.11 (El Capitan). However, an application named X11 is still present there in `/Application/Utilities`. Clicking this application will download and install X11 for you.