# Is there a ssh client like putty for mac?

Tags: mac, putty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PuTTY or xterm for Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/141961/putty-or-xterm-for-mac)

I am looking for software that is somewhat like putty for mac, does this exists?

Comment: Since Putty emulates something that is already native on unix-like operating system just open the terminal and type `ssh` :)

Comment: You can save SSH sessions in Terminal.app:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/65809/Screenshots/Screen%20Shot%202011-08-29%20at%208.56.53%20AM.png

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried Terminal? Open your root volume(usually called Macintosh HD), then Applications, then Utilities, and then Terminal. From there, you can type 'ssh $REMOTE_HOST_NAME', without quotes and replacing $REMOTE_HOST_NAME with the system you want to connect to.

Comment: I do use the installed terminal I am looking for that nice feature though of not having to type:

ssh -l USENAME sub.site.com -p PORT

Comment: Make an alias that already embeds parameters

Comment: Some people like GUI's you know

Answer (score 3):

Sure there is! God save opensource!
You can have it at http://putty.darwinports.com/.
Don't forget to install [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html) first...

Oh, there is [JellyfisSSH](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/8032/jellyfissh) too...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other suggestions, you might also have a look at [Meerkat](http://codesorcery.net/meerkat) (Not developed anymore, free to download)