# Putty-like copy & paste for Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, copy-paste

This is a duplicate of [How can I copy on select in the OS X Terminal like PuTTY does?](https://superuser.com/questions/62609/mac-terminal-copy-on-select-like-putty) but I would like a solution for Linux.

So basically, (how) can I set the selected text to be copied and pasted on right click?

Comment: gnome terminal does that by default, u just need to use Shift-Insert instead of right click to paste

Comment: Right, so then can we make it work on all gnome applications? As the default mouse behavior (paste needed also)

Comment: It's a per-application thing, some applications would need different settings, I'm sure.

Comment: So you want right click to act as "paste" command in all gnome applications? How would you invoke context menu then?

Comment: ok :P you got me. fine, then I can haz paste on terminal?

Comment: Can't you just use the middle button?  Thats how it works in KDE anyway - highlight with the mouse, middle button to paste.

Comment: I know that Xorg does middle click copy, and middle click paste. It should with Xterm, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by Alex, it is , at least, not a good thing make right click act like paste command. On terminal, you can usually set this up in preferences. Alternatively you can use terminator instead of default terminal and get this feature along with a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the middle mouse button, I use this all the time on GNOME based desktops, might work on others however I haven't tried.

When you highlight some text it gets copied in the middle mouse clipboard, then when you want to paste what you have highlighted you press the middle mouse button.

The middle mouse butten clipboard does not overwrite what you have in the normal right click/menu - edit paste clipboard so you can store different things in both clipboards. I believe the normal clipboard does overwrite what you have the middle mouse clipboard when you copy things in to it.

Answer (score -2):

In Ubuntu 12.04, I was able to paste using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.